# Does it make sense to do connection pooling for desktop applications?

Tags: java, database-connection, desktop-application

I'm developing a java desktop application that communicates with a database. There are five users and one database. Each user has their own copy of the software on their machine and the database is located on a computer in the same LAN.

I've read that connection pooling is done only for web-applications. My concern is that, is opening and closing a new connection for every single query going to slow down the software? Does it make sense to use connection pooling in such scenario in particular and desktop applications in general? If opening/closing connections *is* actually a bottleneck and connection pooling is not viable, what is the correct strategy?

Comment: *"I've read that connection pooling is done only for web-applications"* ... not sure where you read that, but stop reading things there. Aside from that, no one can authoritatively answer this question for you; it depends on a lot of factors and the use patterns of the application.

Comment: I disagree with the closure of this question as "primarily opinion-based".  Connection pooling is *always* preferable to either long-lived or frequently opened/closed connections.  The later creates load on the DB server, whether the application is a desktop application or a server application.  The former (long-lived) carries with it the risk of connection loss and recovery which requires substantial application-level logic to cope with.  A connection pool, by checking "freshness" before returning the connection, greatly simplifies application logic and demonstrably reduces failures.

Answer (score 4):

Connection pools can help in a number of ways.  In a webapp, of course, it can help reduce load by holding connections open to reduce the time/overhead of reconnecting with each request.  You can get *some* of that in a desktop app but I doubt you'd notice the difference.  One of the biggest unsung benefits, however, is automatic reconnection handling.  Depending on  how your app is set up, you could get transparent (or at least translucent) support for reconnecting if your connection should ever drop for free.

Comment: Good reply!  It would still be useful to know 1) if the clients are connecting directly to the database, and 2) exactly what kind of database.

Comment: @FoggyDay the clients are directly connected to a database that is either MySql or MS-Sql Server.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, it depends.

It will depend on the complexity of the application and the number of simultaneous queries you want to make to the database.

If all your doing is making a single call from time to time, then it's probably not worth effort to have a pool, but keep a single connection available.

If, on the other hand, if you are making a number of queries, sometimes simultaneously, it would be of benefit to have event a simple pool.

The more complex the problem becomes  the more benefit you'll get from having a connection pool

This, of course, is a balancing act. You don't want a lot of connections sitting around dosing nothing for a long time if you have help it.

Comment: Thanks. There aren't so many queries going to the db. But my point is, if one of the users wants to... say insert a new record, is there going to be a lag due to making a connection?

Comment: Making the connection, possibly.  It will depend on a few factors.  In a case like this, it might be better either use a single connection or a small pool of connections.  A pool that can recycle connections would be better, so if a connection has been open for a period of time, it can be closed automatically and when required would be opened again.  So if you were doing a number of queries in (relatively) quick succession, you would keep that connection, for example...

Answer (score 0):

Connection pooling is a "server side thing".  It really only makes sense if you pool connections where the database lives, for example, on an application server that might sit between your database and your clients.

Q: Do you have an app server, or any kind of middleware?  Or are your clients all connecting directly to the database?

If the latter, what *kind* of database?  Each vendor has their own extensions that might help.

Comment: Then apparently all those desktop DB tools are doing it wrong ...